# Why doesn't Django automatically create the templates folder?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates

when I use django2.0 I met an error:**django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: name.html**. I find the problem is that the django didn't create the template directory automatically. I use command`django-admin startproject demo` to start my project, but I can't see the template directory as tutorial.
May I ask what's the problem?

Comment: What tutorial? In the Django tutorial, it does not mention creating a `templates` directory: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project It thus looks that  the directory (and the `name.html` file) was created by the tutorial you used.

Comment: Hi @Willem Van Onsem, your guss might be right. the tutorial probably miss something.

Comment: Django `startproject` does not create the templates for you.  You have to do that, but it is as simple as creating a folder called `templates`, then within that folder another folder with the name of your app, and within *that* folder your name.html.  Why all this?  This is how Django finds the correct template.  It *looks for*, but it does not **create** a templates folder. My suggestion is to check back on that tutorial to see if you missed a step, or try the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project) already mentioned by @WillemVanOnsem.

Comment: Because there's no reason it should. Django allows you to configure any folders to keep the templates in. **It can be named anything**. You can even have multiple templates folders. Hence, it doesn't make sense to automatically create a *"templates"* folder.

Comment: If you are just getting started, please use Django 3.2 or 4.0; the 2 series is no longer supported and will not receive bug fixes or security updates!